# NumberFormatException PrimeFaces TreeTable

Tags: primefaces, treetable

I am currently working with Primefaces and treetables. My treetable works well except one case. Let me set a little example to explain the problem:

The treetable is like this:

- Item1.1

  - Item2.1
- Item1.2
- Item1.3

At the beginning, the tree is collapsed.
The treetable is defined like this:

```
<p:treeTable id="treetable" value="#{bean.root}" var="node" selectionMode="single" selection="#{bean.selectedNode}">
```

And I have those ajax calls in it:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.onSelect}" />
```

Everything is running well in general. The node selected is updated whatever the level of the node. The problem is with this case:

(All is collapsed)

1. extend Item1.1
2. select Item2.1
3. collapse Item1.1
4. select Item1.2

And here I got the exception:

```
INFO: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,1"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.findTreeNode(UITree.java:120)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.findTreeNode(UITree.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.setRowKey(UITree.java:80)
    at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTableRenderer.decodeSelection(TreeTableRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTableRenderer.decode(TreeTableRenderer.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processDecodes(UITree.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTable.processDecodes(TreeTable.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:402)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the type of `#{bean.selectedNode}`?

Comment: The type is a TreeNode.

Answer (score 0):

This is PrimeFaces bug in **treetable.js**, [there is issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6007).

The problem is because *unselectAllNodes()* function in **treetable.js** does not clear **selection** array variable but it should be empty after exit from this function:

```
unselectAllNodes: function() {
    var selectedNodes = this.tbody.children('tr.ui-state-highlight');

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
        this.unselectNode(selectedNodes.eq(i), true);
    }
}
```

When parent row with previous selected row is expanded this bug not occur, because all visible selected rows (search by *ui-state-highlight* attribute) unselects with removing from  **selection** array variable. But when parent row is collapsed, tbody.children*('tr.ui-state-highlight')* return empty list, and **selection** array variable have previous value plus new selectable value separated by comma.

Good news that from PrimeFaces 4.0 release this bug was fixed. because [this commit](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/diff?spec=svn10078&r=10078&format=side&path=/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.js&old_path=/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.js&old=10076) have been inluded to release. One small difference: **selection** array variable have been renamed to **selections** by other commits.

```
unselectAllNodes: function() {
    var selectedNodes = this.tbody.children('tr.ui-state-highlight');
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
        this.unselectNode(selectedNodes.eq(i), true);
    }

    this.selections = [];
    this.writeSelections();
}
```